# display data in laravel

Tags: php, web-applications, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

im working on a gradebook software and i have a litte problem with the displaying of the grades.

I have typed in the following line in my view-file: 
`<p>{{!! $gradesArray = $user->grades !!}}</p>`

But as result I got the whole Array in json-format:
`{[{"id":"10","grade":"1.3","user_id":"6","course_id":"3","created_at":"2016-01-08 16:31:14","updated_at":"2016-01-08 16:31:14","deleted_at":null},{"id":"11","grade":"1.7","user_id":"6","course_id":"2","created_at":"2016-01-08 22:59:43","updated_at":"2016-01-08 22:59:43","deleted_at":null},{"id":"12","grade":"2.0","user_id":"6","course_id":"1","created_at":"2016-01-09 13:26:09","updated_at":"2016-01-09 13:26:09","deleted_at":null}]}`

What can I do to display only the grades and courses?

Comment: Use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{!! !!}}` Just a note, it won't solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach($user->grades as $grade)
{{ $grade->grade }}
@endforeach
```